# How to exit nested while loop

Tags: javascript

```
var userName = input.question('Please enter your name: ');
console.log('\nHi ' + userName + ', please select your choice:');
var choice = input.question('1. Display Name 2. Display Age');
```

```
while (choice == 1 {
 console.log ("Hello");
 var choice = input.questionFloat('\1. Display Name 2. Display Age');
}
while (choice == 2 {
 console.log ("Hello");
  var subChoice = input.question('1. Display date 2. Display time');
  while (subChoice == 1) {
             console.log ("Hello");
  }
  while (subChoice == 2) {
             console.log('\nHi ' + userName + ', please select your choice:');
             var choice = input.questionFloat('\1. Display Name 2. Display Age');
  }
}
```

The first block of code is asking the user their name, after which the user will be required to enter either choice 1 or 2.

The choice that the user chose will be stored in `choice`. I have both `choice` as well as `subChoice`. `subChoice` comes after the user selects `choice`. In this case, in order to access the `subChoice` `1` or `2`, the user will have to select `choice` 2 first. If I want to exit the `subChoice`, I would have to select `subChoice` 2 which will bring me back to the choices for `choice` 1 & 2.

However, the problem that I am facing is that after returning to choice 1 or 2, the variable `userName` does not contain a value or string any more. In addition, when I select other choices i.e `choice` 1, it does not do anything but re-prompting me the same thing with no `userName` and loops in the `subChoice == 2` itself.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: 1) Please don't [vandalise your own posts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72986507/5211833). Vandalism will always be reverted. 2) You're free to delete your own posts (when the system allows you to), however, deleting a post to literally repost it to get around a down vote may result in a question ban. The correct way of handling this kind of situation is to go back to your original post, [edit] it to include better information and try to improve the post that way.

Comment: Hi, my mistake. However, this is quite important

Answer (score 0):

Use if structure agains while loop. The closing parenteses was missing almost every while conditions. You used var agains let, and you redeclared the choice variable multiple times.

I cannot run the code here, but somthing like this should work:

```js
let userName = input.question('Please enter your name: ');
console.log('\nHi ' + userName + ', please select your choice:');
let choice = input.question('1. Display Name 2. Display Age');

if (choice == 1) {
  console.log ("Hello");
  choice = input.questionFloat('\1. Display Name 2. Display Age');
}
if (choice == 2) {
  console.log ("Hello");
  let subChoice = input.question('1. Display date 2. Display time');
  if (subChoice == 1) {
   console.log ("Hello");
  }
  if (subChoice == 2) {
   console.log('\nHi ' + userName + ', please select your choice:');
   choice = input.questionFloat('\1. Display Name 2. Display Age');
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried using If but I want it to always re-prompt instead of only re-prompting it once

Comment: Then you should give a 3rd option for every question. 3 == exit.

Comment: I just want to know why the var doesnt pass it through nested while loop ?